# git best practice - how to separate development from testing and deployment

Tags: git, svn

I want to change my SVN repo with Git and after that I want to separate the development, test and deployment from each other. Does anybody know a "HOW-TO" or "Best practice" for these topics?

Best regards,
SK

Comment: You are asking more than one question.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know git is a bit different than svn in how things are done.
There are as many opinions on how to do things as there are developers.

If you wan't to go open source then I suggest to read up on strategies from numerous open source projects.

Since you say "my repo" I'm guessing no one else will push to it.

A simple strategy is to keep development on branches that pushes to master. When you feel you have a release candidate, label it and start testing.
If you have correctional changes, branch out from the point of the label and correct them.
But only if you have made functional changes after the point of the label.
Make sure to insert those correctional changes back into the development branch/master.

Once you feel the testing is done, label the point with a release label.